# In Civilization VI, do farms benefit from fresh water?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civilization VI, do farms benefit from being adjacent to fresh water? If so, does it matter if it's from a river, lake, natural wonder, or other source? Does the benefit require any technology or civic?

I recall fresh water being beneficial in earlier versions of Civilization, but I can't find any benefit documented for Civ VI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, water does not affect farm production.

It does, however, affect the base housing of a city- making it a good spot to settle.